# youtube-dl: ERROR: This video is not available... Which video?

Tags: command-line, video, youtube, youtube-dl

When using `youtube-dl` version 2019.07.16, if I run the following command:

```
$ youtube-dl --get-id https://youtube.com/user/youtube_channel
```

I will sometimes get an output like this example:

```
dIJxA-_1MVM
gE3xeJC_G_L
ITll8zhfvwk
ERROR: This video is not available.
dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

This will happen if the user or YouTube removes the video in question. The only issue is, this does not say *which* video this message is referring to.

Am I just missing one of youtube-dl's many flags?

Comment: Is it possible this refers to the video ID listed directly before or afterwards? Could you provide a channel URL for testing?

Comment: Are you trying to look up a channel with the program or a specific video? If a video, I can help you.

Comment: @dessert Using `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCothzhiulmMsaF5rQp5XLgQ` under a USA VPN shows me this output: https://pastebin.com/raw/8b83a3e2 and every ID listed is valid. It does not show the errored ID anywhere.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife It is a channel, but even running a completely random and invalid URL gives the same output. Here's an example: https://pastebin.com/raw/PC63nkK1 I also included a video URL that was a real video at one time until the uploader removed it.

Comment: Hi leetbacoon- I tested your link and you are correct, it's unavailable for me to. It looks like a possible bug, check out this website. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/15417.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife Hi, the missing video is normal. I was looking to see if youtube-dl would print out which video id is the problematic one. Either way I had a friend of mine submit a suggestion on youtube-dl github. Thank you

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Comment: @leetbacoon- I am sorry I thought I could answer your question but I don't know why it's not working, I apologize.

Comment: @BJsgoodlife No need to apologize :) I appreciate your help. I don't think youtube-dl supports this feature natively. Hopefully this can be added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The flag you want is `-i` for `--ignore-errors`.

Comment: Well, not quite. `--ignore-errors` allows youtube-dl to continue grabbing video IDs even after it finds a dead link, has trouble connecting, has disk write issues, etc. I'm trying to find the video id (https⁣://www.youtube.com/watch?v= **leTpySlsl50** ) of the video that gives the error